# For any monomial ordering, $1\leq m$ for any monomial $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $R$ be a ring.
>
> Let $\leq$ be a well-ordering on the set of (monic) monomials in $R[X_1,...,X_n]$.
>
> Then, $\leq$ is said to be a monomial ordering iff $mm_1\leq mm_2$ whenever $m_1\leq m_2$ for monomials $m,m_1,m_2$.

Under this definition, Dummit&Foote states that "it is an easy task to show that for any monomial ordering, $1\leq m$ for any monomial $m$" in p.317

However, I have no idea where to start to prove this.

How do I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ordered $\implies $ every chain has a minimum, but

$$1>m \implies 1>m>m^2>\dots$$